# Get Img element Using src link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have collection of "img" tags in "IFRAME".

> i have to get the specified img element using src value

```
 <iframe class="k-conent">
    <html>
    <body>
    <img src="http://localhost:59023/ImageBrowser/GetImageData?path=download.jpg&amp;companyId=50c2ca58-4036-4f0b-9a15-a3b000df6980" alt=""><img src="http://localhost:59023/ImageBrowser/GetImageData?path=itm_2013-04-23_09-56-06_1.jpg&amp;companyId=50c2ca58-4036-4f0b-9a15-a3b000df6980" alt=""><br _moz_dirty="true">
    </body>
    </html>
    </iframe>
```

My current implementation is like this :

```
var findalbelsrcvalue="http://localhost:59023/ImageBrowser/GetImageData?Path=download.jpg;companyId=50c2ca58-4036-4f0b-9a15-a3b000df6980"
     var $content = $('.k-content').contents();
            var $body = $content.find('body');
            var $imagetag = $content.find('img');
            if ($imagetag.length > 0) {
                $imagetag.each(function() {
if($(this).attr("src")==findalbelsrcvalue){
                    var width = $('txtWidth').val();
                    var height = $('txtWidth').val();
            switch ($("input[name=Alignment]:checked").val()) {
                case "Left":
                    $(this).css('float', 'left');
                case "Middle":
                    $(this).css('display', 'block');
                    $(this).css('margin-left', 'auto');
                    $(this).css('margin-right', 'auto');
                case "Right":
                    $(this).css('float', 'right');
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
}
           });
    }
```

it worked for me but it looped every img tag. It does not make sense. Anyone help me out how can find the img tag.

> Like
>
> ```
> `var element=$("srclink").contents().find("img");`
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var srcvalue="http://localhost:59023/ImageBrowser/GetImageData?     Path=download.jpg;companyId=50c2ca58-4036-4f0b-9a15-a3b000df6980";


   console.log($('.k-content').contents().find("body img[src='"+findalbelsrcvalue+"']"));
```

try this

Comment: its worked.but few typos  i have edit ..Thanks once again master

Answer (score 2):

```
var element=$("img[src='<src-value>']");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try **attribute equals selector [name=”value”]** in jquery:

```
the_img_el = $("img[src='http://localhost:59023/ImageBrowser/GetImageData?path=download.jpg&amp;companyId=50c2ca58-4036-4f0b-9a15-a3b000df6980']" )
```